# Paint QGraphicsScene on mono QImage faster

Tags: image, qt

I have to render `QGraphicsScene` onto an image (or a printer).

The time and memory used can be very large, on a device type that has severe limitations.

So I optimized upstream items: at the point where I render, all the items on scene are mono (either simple objects with a single color, or `QGraphicsPixmapItem` containing images already dithered).

```
image = QImage(view->scene()->sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_Mono);
image.fill(QColor(Qt::color0).rgb());
painter.begin(&image);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
view->scene()->render(&painter);
painter.end();
```

This step is still taking a significant amount of time.

Is there any way to speed it up, by perhaps ensuring that there is no dithering (`ThresholdDither`) ? Or any other method that may be faster ?

Comment: If you look into the raster paint engine backend, you'll possibly notice that mono image painting may not be optimized, or is done by painting onto 32 bit color temporary and then converting. Have you verified that rendering directly onto the printer device (in postscript) rather than onto an image doesn't work better? It well might.

Comment: What do you mean rendering directly onto printer device ? (at his moment I am not sure if a print call will be used directly, or a bitmap needs to be output and forwarded to driver)

Comment: Start the painter on a `QPrinter` instance, then render the scene there. Why even use a mono image? Otherwise, you could render to a pdf, it'd still be smaller than an image, and faster to do.

Comment: A mono image will be fed to a printer head, who will likely accept bitmap. A normal color scene is color separated so each color is sent to a different print head.

Comment: How do you deal with that printer? Color separation is normally done by the printer driver. Why do you think that you need to do it yourself?

Comment: The printer driver does not exist yet... it will be integrated with the application (or at least a print library)... and it seems simpler (more lightweight) to separate color at vector level, instead of saving and dithering extremely large images on a small device (in fact a full color image of worst case scenario size would not even fit)

Comment: You need to start digging into the raster engine and see what it really does when it paints on a mono image. Most likely it's not very optimal at all.